# Fetch specific column by using multiple tables, using native query and interface based projection

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

my need is to use native query and interface-based projection in JPA to fetch the record from multiple tables

```
 @Query(value = "select cm.center_code as centerCode,cm.center_name as centerName,es.exam_slot_code as slotName,ecm.total_seat_allocated as seatAllocatedCount,ecityM.city_name as centerCity,afcatg.name as groupName from center_master cm  "
            + "inner join centre_examslot_mapping cesm  "
            + "on cm.center_id = cesm.centre_id  "
            + "inner join exam_city_master ecityM "
            + "on  ecityM.city_id= cm.center_city_id  "
            + "inner join exam_slot  es  "
            + "on cesm.exam_slot_id= es.exam_slot_id "
            + "inner join exam_center_mapping ecm  "
            + "on cesm.centre_examslot_mappingid = ecm.centre_examslot_mappingid  "
            + "inner join afcat_group afcatg  "
            + "on ecm.afcat_group_id= afcatg.afcat_group_id  "
            + "where cm.center_code= ?1", nativeQuery = true)
 public List<GetSlotGroupSeatAllocatedFromDB> getData(String centerCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `projections` you have to define an interface with attributes you need with prefix 'get'. Your class GetSlotGroupSeatAllocatedFromDB must be an interface implemented like this:

```
public Interface GetSlotGroupSeatAllocatedFromDB{

Integer getCenterCode();
String getCenterName();
String getSlotName();
Integer getSeatAllocatedCount();
String getCenterCity();
String getGroupName();
}
```

I supposed the attributes types (Integer o String, maybe your centerCode is String...)